# How to create virtual appliance like bitname and turnkey linux

Tags: virtualization, bitnami

i have a question i am bit of a linux user sort of programmer but i couldn't understand is how to develop your own virtual appliance similar to bitnami and turnkey and if there is a way please tell me!!

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [TKLPatch](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/tklpatch), a simple tool for customizing and extending any of 100+ appliances in the TurnKey Linux library. The resulting patch can be used to generate an ISO that can be installed in a VM or on real hardware.

If you have any questions or need help, feel free to post to the TurnKey forum.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated info**
Hopefully my necro-posting adds some value...

The new TurnKey build tool is [TKLDev](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/tkldev). It uses a similar paradigm to TKLPatch, but instead of requiring you to start with an ISO; it builds completely from source.

So long as you can script the install (and there's almost always a way that you can) and it will work on Debian, then you can build yourself a software appliance in a load of different build types (inc. OVA, VMDK, hybrid ISO etc) using TurnKey Linux's [TKLDev](https://www.turnkeylinux.org/docs/tkldev) build engine. The major VM platform that it doesn't (yet) support is Hyper-V but the ISO installs.